# How to construct and extract value from simple HTTPS request in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a simple HTTPS request -
https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-eur/ticker

In the browser this returns one object. What's the simplest code that will allow me to retrieve and display this object (as is) in the terminal of Node?

```
    const https = require('https')
    const url = https.get('https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-eur/ticker')

    const myObject = JSON.parse(url)
    console.log(myObject)
```

A simple copy / paste of the above code in VSC returns the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.

Comment: Can you please explain the problem a little more? What is your current solution giving, and what do you expect?

Comment: Hi, This code is giving me 'unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'. If I console log just the url I get a mile of data related to the object but not the actual object. I want to display the array with all the values as displayed in the browser.

Comment: I have a feeling I need to create a request object that includes a 'user-agent' header, but havn't covered this yet, just what Iv read. At the moment the object is anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mamba76, welcome to the SO community. Please use Node.js `node-fetch` package. It is much simpler to use. You can install it using `npm install`.

Following code might help:

```
"use strict";
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function getValue() {

  // Invoke the API.
  // Wait until data is fetched.
  let response = await fetch('https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-eur/ticker');

  let value = await response.json();

  return value;
}

getValue().then(result => {console.log(result.price);});
```

As a good practice, always assume that API calls over the HTTP (whether in your own network or outside) might take time to return data and hence you should use `async-await` pattern to make these requests.

Comment: Thanks very much Prasad! This is exactly what I needed to do. When you get over  hurdles like this it just inspires me to learn even more. Havn't used 'await' function yet but looks simpler than the 'data = data + chunk' method learned so far.

Comment: In Prasad's example how can I store the object(result) or value(result.price) as an array or variable, respectively, so this data can be used or exported like a normal objects/variables?

Comment: Feels like Im over looking something simple but when I try to assign 'const myObject = result' I keep getting 'myObject not defined'?

Comment: Is it best to open a new question or continue from here?

Comment: Im revisiting my questions to see if I can help others further now that I understand what Stack is about! I guess this question was downVoted as I didn't give the output. I assumed it would be easy for someone to copy/paste the text into VSC and also that if you didn't have VSC you wouldn't understand what the error would mean anyway! So would appreciate if someone would upvote my question if it helped you. It can seem like heading into a pack of wolves armed with only a spoon when your a newbie trying to get help on here!

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Akshay.N's answer and without using external dependencies,

```
const https = require('https')

https.get("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-eur/ticker",res=>{
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => { body += chunk; });
    res.on('end', () => {
        const myObject = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(myObject);
    })
})
```

Now, what we're doing here is waiting on the `data` event as long as the data is coming in, and appending it to the variable `body`. Once the `end` event is encountered, we take that as a signal that all data has been received and we can proceed to parse the body into an object using `JSON.parse` (assuming the data was serialized in JSON; if it wasn't `JSON.parse` will throw an error).

This tutorial is helpful: https://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:-

```
https.get("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-eur/ticker",res=>{
    res.on('data', (chunk) => { console.log(JSON.parse(chunk))})
})
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay, that is a simpler version of similar stuff Iv read but again outputs 'User-Agent header is required. Looks like this request needs to be broken down somewhat. Ill do some more reading..

Comment: @Akshay.N You're missing the `end` event. Check out my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. Akashdeep's amendment looks very similar to the way Im learning breaking it down makes it easier to understand. I knew there are different ways to achieve the same result so Ill be coming back to this for reference.

Comment: Although the amended code still gives the terminal message 'User-Agent header is required'

Answer (score -1):

With node (you need request module) :

```
// display object
(require("request")).get({

    url: "myurl",
    json: true

 }, function(e,r,b){
     console.log(b);
 });

// display as string
(require("request")).get({

    url: "myurl",
    json: false

 }, function(e,r,b){

     console.log(b);

 });
```

With just curl in your terminal (without node)

```
curl myurl
```

Comment: It would've been easier to understand had you explained that the code requires the `request` module, and if all the code wasn't in one line. It can be hard to unpack for someone learning node anew like the OP.